# Check Internet Usage using JAVA

Tags: java, networking, getrusage

How can I Check upload and download data capacities using Java Code?
(in internet or local area network)

Comment: Do you mean the connection speed?

Comment: no. I need check usage in network. Upload and download usages.

Answer (score 0):

Java applet and this link [internet](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-personal-proxy-servers-written-in-java) might work

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for usage statistics, you could use a packet capture library (such as [Pcap4J](https://www.pcap4j.org/) or [Jpcap](http://jpcap.github.io/)) to formulate your own. I prefer Pcap4J because it has more examples and documentation, and it is more up-to-date.